# The way to write protractor scenarios

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, end-to-end

Let's say that the angular app contains two pages: contacts (contains the table with a list of contacts and a button "add new contact") and new contact page (with form for adding new contact). And I would like to write that scenario:

1. Click add button
2. Check that "new contacts" page opens
3. Input contacts data
4. Press add button
5. Check that new contacts is in table

For these pages i have page objects with functions like "click some button", "input some field" and all functions returns promises.

What is the best way to write test scenario: using js chaining like

```
contactPage.clickAddButton()
.then(function () {
    return newContactPage.checkUrl();
})
.then(function () {
    return newContactPage.inputData(data);
})
.then(function () {
    return newContactPage.clickAddButton();
})
.then(function () {
    return checkContact(data);
})
.then(function (succes) {
}, function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

or I can write like this:

```
contactPage.clickAddButton();
newContactPage.checkUrl();
newContactPage.inputData(data);
newContactPage.clickAddButton();
checkContact(data);
```

And does it make sense to split the scenario into multiple "it" functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to resolve the promises explicitly. Protractor has a [Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) and handles the queue of promises naturally out of the box. Since this is a single scenario, you may leave it inside a single `it()`, unless you don't repeat yourself:

```
contactPage.clickAddButton();
newContactPage.checkUrl();
newContactPage.inputData(data);
newContactPage.clickAddButton();
checkContact(data);
```

Comment: Ok, but how write scenarios if i would like to use value which resolved from function, e.g.
    var getData = function () {
      var def = Q.defer();
      var data;
      ...
      if(data) {
        def.resolve(data);
      } else {
        def.reject(new Error('Data not found!'));
      }
      return def.promise;
    };

How can I get data in scenario?

Comment: @qweasd yeah, if you need the resolved result of a function call - you'll need `then()`. Good point, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If sticking to protractor, you should handle as [answered by alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33082507/1654818).

But if you wanted to keep the chain of promises explicit (moved away from protractor, consistent with app coding format, etc), then it could be rewritten like so:

```
contactPage.clickAddButton()
  .then(newContactPage.checkUrl) // Must resolve `data` for next function
  .then(newContactPage.inputData) 
  .then(newContactPage.clickAddButton) // Must resolve `data` for next function
  .then(checkContact)
  .then(function (success) {
    // Test passes...
  }, function (error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

But if you are using protractor it is much cleaner to write it as [answered by alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33082507/1654818).